# GPS latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have some code to get latitude and longitude and this code working in local server but not working in real server ,why?

```
<body>
<td align="center">{{res.product_id.Arabic_name}}</td>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/style/file.css'/>
<br><br><br>
<div align="center" style="width=40%" id="bt">
<p><a href="/start/1"><button class="dropbtn" >العربية</button></a></p>
 <p><a href="/start/4"><button class="dropbtn">Türk</button></a></p>
<p><a href="/start/2"><button class="dropbtn">ENGLISH</button></a></p>
<p><a href="/start/3"><button class="dropbtn">Русский</button></a></p>

</div>
<center><h2 id="loc" style="visibility:hidden">أنت بعيد عن المقهى يرجى 
التواجد في المقهى لتشغيل النظام</h2></center>
<p name="lat" id="demo" style="visibility:hidden"  ></p>
<p name="long" id="demo1" style="visibility:hidden"></p>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var y = document.getElementById("demo1");

if (navigator.geolocation) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
   x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";

  }

 function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML =  position.coords.latitude
 y.innerHTML= position.coords.longitude;
 var L=position.coords.latitude
 var K=position.coords.longitude;

if ((L !=21.556428800000003)||(K!=39.211827199999995)) {
       document.getElementById("bt").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("loc").style.visibility = 'visible';
 }
}


</script>
</body>
 {% endblock %}
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "not working"? What is it doing, and what do you want it to do? What differences are there between your development and production servers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how relevant this is, but if you're working with server-side languages (you mentioned local versus "real" server), PHP has a library that deals with latitude and longitudes, and you can even do some calculations with the values.

https://packagist.org/packages/mjaschen/phpgeo

If you use Composer with PHP to install dependencies, then it's as easy as typing "composer require mjaschen/phpgeo" into your command line. If you're unfamiliar with Composer, take a look here: https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm working with django and I have trial python domain(ramadan.pythonanywhere.com) in local server working without any problem but when I uploaded this code to trial domain dose not get the latitude and longitute